# Human Genome Alignment and Variant Calling Benchmarks

Tags: gatk, adam

I am doing a project that requires bench-marking the performance of computational tools for alignment and variant calling of human genome sequencing data. In particular I would like to establish benchmarks comparing the performance of [GATK](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/) and [ADAM](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/adam)/[Avocado](https://github.com/bigdatagenomics/avocado).

My main question is which genomic data-sets should I use as the input to the data processing pipeline. In Frank Nothaft's (author of ADAM and Avodaco) [thesis](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2017/EECS-2017-204.html) he reports bench-marking the processing of NA12878 from the 1,000 genome's project in Avocado as compared to GATK's HalotypeCaller. He also reports benchmarking on 270 samples from the Simons Genome Diversity Data-set.

I am interested in reproducing this portion of his work, but do not know where I can get a hold of these datasets. Where can I get a copy of the NA12878 genome (BAM file) and also were can I get aligned samples from Simons Genome Diversity Data-set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### NA12878

- My recommendation: download raw reads from [Illumina BaseSpace](https://basespace.illumina.com/home/index) and do alignment yourself. Aligning ~40X worth of human reads takes overnight with ~16 CPU cores.
- You can acquire [Platinum Genome](https://www.illumina.com/platinumgenomes.html) data [from ENA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/ERX168836). There is a BAM available for download, but that was done by Illumina's own aligner against a wrong reference genome. You'd better do alignment by yourself. Another problem with this dataset is it is too good to be representative. Modern data are worse.
- GIAB provides BAMs here:

  ```
  ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nih.gov/giab/ftp/data/NA12878/NIST_NA12878_HG001_HiSeq_300x/
  ```

  It is not "typical", either.

#### SGDP

- Instructions on downloading SGDP BAMs are available [on this page](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/simons-genome-diversity-project/), in particular [this Word document](http://simonsfoundation.s3.amazonaws.com/share/SCDA/datasets/2014_11_12/StepstodownloadtheSGDPdataset_v4.docx). Warning: you need ~30TB disk space for these BAMs. I also heard it is tricky to download data.
- There is apparently a mirror [from cancer genomics cloud](https://docs.cancergenomicscloud.org/v1.0/docs/simons-genome-diversity-project-sgdp-dataset). I don't know how easy it is to access.

Comment: I'm having some trouble finding the fastq files for NA12878 on Illumina BaseSpace. Do you have any suggestions on where to find these?